# Path always returning false when trying to manually put a path with Rust

Tags: rust

I've been learning Rust, and I'm having a bit of a problem with this code.

```rust
let path = Path::new(&return_path); // return path is the user input

println!("{}", path.is_dir());

match path.is_dir() {
    true => print!("yep its true"),
    false => print!("nope its false")
}
```

This always returns false. I'm trying to make a system where the user can provide a absolute path for example `/home/user/Downloads` and it checks if that is a valid directory to insert a file.

Comment: What happens if you print the string path with `println!("{:?}", return_path);` ? I'd guess that your path is wrong and has a newline at the end or something.

Comment: Does the path in fact `exists()`?

Comment: I suggest trying to write a file to the directory, and surface any I/O error that may occur to the user. There are so many ways writing a file to a directory can go wrong, and the path not pointing to an existing directory is but one of them, so checking this doesn't really buy you much.

Comment: `/home/user` is the Home path for my Linux system. `/Downloads` is basically the download folder which indeed does exist.

Comment: Incidentally, a `match` on a `bool` is usually just done with an `if` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe double check `&return_path`? Here's a snippet to verify path works as expected:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let arg = env::args().nth(1).unwrap(); // Get first argument

    println!("Inspecting path {}", arg);
    let path = Path::new(&arg);
    println!("exists?: {}", path.exists());
    println!("is_file?: {}", path.is_file());
    println!("is_dir?: {}", path.is_dir());
    println!("is_symlink?: {}", path.is_symlink());
    if let Ok(full_path) = path.canonicalize() {
        println!("Canonical path: {:?}", full_path);
    } else {
        println!("Couldn't canonicalize path");
    }
}
```

And on my system:

```
> ./tmp /home/me/Downloads
Inspecting path /home/me/Downloads
exists?: true
is_file?: false
is_dir?: true
is_symlink?: false
Canonical path: "/home/me/Downloads"
```